# How to display Product Attribute name instead of slug in each loop?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I have a attribute loop and attempting to display the Attributes names in the first  selection of the `<select>` drop-down. But every-time I echo the name, the slug is displayed. So "`pa_attribute_metal`" is being displayed instead of "Metal".

Below is my current loop & the code I'm currently using. Clearly `$attribute['name']` is not pulling the actual name.

```
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();

foreach ($attributes as $attribute):

   echo '<select name="'.$attribute['name'].'" class="example">';
   echo '<option name="'.$attribute['name'].'">'.$attribute['name'].'</option>';
   echo '</select>';

endforeach;
```

What is the best way to pull the actual display name of the attribute through the each loop & display it in the `<option>`?

Comment: is it necessary to use `echo '<select name="'.$attribute['name'].'" class="example">';` inside the loop? debug, `print_r($attributes)` before foreach start and share the result

Comment: Using multiple dropdowns since there is multiple attributes in the product page. Thus the `<select>` within the foreach.

Comment: @devpro here is the print: Array ( [pa_attribute-metal] => WC_Product_Attribute Object ( [data:protected] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => pa_attribute-metal [options] => Array ( [0] => 28 [1] => 29 [2] => 27 [3] => 26 ) [position] => 1 [visible] => 1 [variation] => ) ) )

Comment: your code is 100% fine, check ` [name] => pa_attribute-metal` u do not have name here

Comment: i think `$product->get_attributes()` should be `$_product->get_attributes()` isnt it?

Comment: Why do you create a `select` for each item?

Comment: @devpro I checked, how do I give it a name? I checked the Wordpress backend and it definitely has a name! If not I can just do some Javascript and change it by force.

Comment: ok, try it like `$attributes = $_product->get_attributes('pa_metal');
`

Comment: @devpro What about the other attributes included with the foreach? You're right that the display name is not appearing. So I've done some Javascript to force the name change to something readable.

Comment: then create an array with your attribute name and use them as you need. just suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="attribute_taxonomy" class="attribute_taxonomy">
    <option value=""><?php esc_html_e('product attribute', 'woocommerce'); ?></option>
    <?php
    global $wc_product_attributes;

    // Array of defined attribute taxonomies.
    $attribute_taxonomies = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();

    if (!empty($attribute_taxonomies)) {
        foreach ($attribute_taxonomies as $tax) {
            $attribute_taxonomy_name = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($tax->attribute_name);
            $label = $tax->attribute_label ? $tax->attribute_label : $tax->attribute_name;
            echo '<option value="' . esc_attr($attribute_taxonomy_name) . '">' . esc_html($label) . '</option>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   while ($query->have_posts()) {
      $query->next_post();
      $result[] = $query->post;
      $taxonomy = 'pa_size';
      $meta = get_post_meta($result[$i]->ID, 'attribute_'. $taxonomy, true);
      $term = get_term_by('slug', $meta, $taxonomy);
      array_push($arrayValue, $term);
  }
  for ($j = 0; $j<count($arrayValue); $j++){
     echo $arrayValue[$j]->name;
  }
```